# Proof that if $f$ is integrable then so is $\left|f\right|$ with the classical definition of the Riemann Integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ be integrable. Prove $\left|f\right|$ is integrable with the definition of the integral using the Riemann sums (not the Darboux one).

I think the way to go is to use the following two theorems:

Cauchy criterion: A function $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is integrable if and only if $\forall \epsilon>0\exists \delta>0$ so that for any pair of tagged partitions $\dot{\mathcal{P}},\dot{\mathcal{Q}}$ of $[a,b]$
\begin{equation}\left\|\mathcal{P}\right\|,\left\|\mathcal{Q}\right\|<\delta\implies 
\left|S(f,\dot{\mathcal{P}})-S(f,\dot{\mathcal{Q}})\right|<\epsilon\end{equation}

or the simpler squeeze theorem:
$f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is integrable if and only if $\forall \epsilon>0$ there exist integrable functions $g,h:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ so that
\begin{equation}g\le f\le h\text{ and }\int_a^bh-g<\epsilon\end{equation}

When I tried the Cauchy Criterion, I couldn't prove 
\begin{equation}\left|S(\left|f\right|,\dot{\mathcal{P}})-S(\left|f\right|,\dot{\mathcal{Q}})\right|<\left|S(f,\dot{\mathcal{P}})-S(f,\dot{\mathcal{Q}})\right|\end{equation}
which doesn't really seem to be true. With the squeeze theorem I can't construct $h$. Any ideas?

EDIT:
$$\left|S(\left|f\right|,\dot{\mathcal{P}})-S(\left|f\right|,\dot{\mathcal{Q}})\right|\le\left|S(f,\dot{\mathcal{P}})-S(f,\dot{\mathcal{Q}})\right|\iff \\
\left|\sum_{i=1}^n(\left|f(t_i)\right|-\left|f(t'_i)\right|)(x_i-x_{i-1})\right|\le \left|\sum_{i=1}^n(f(t_i)-f(t'_i))(x_i-x_{i-1})\right|\iff\\
-\left|\sum_{i=1}^nf(t_i)-f(t'_i)\right|\le 
\sum_{i=1}^n\left|f(t_i)\right|-\left|f(t'_i)\right|\le
\left|\sum_{i=1}^nf(t_i)-f(t'_i)\right|
$$
Now,
$$\left|\sum_{i=1}^nf(t_i)-f(t'_i)\right|\ge\sum_{i=1}^n \left|f(t_i)-f(t'_i)\right|\ge \sum_{i=1}^n \left|f(t_i)\right|-\left|f(t'_i)\right|
$$
and
$$-\left|\sum_{i=1}^nf(t_i)-f(t'_i)\right|\le-\sum_{i=1}^n \left|f(t_i)-f(t'_i)\right|\le -\sum_{i=1}^n -\left|f(t_i)\right|+\left|f(t'_i)\right|=\sum_{i=1}^n \left|f(t_i)\right|-\left|f(t'_i)\right|
$$

Comment: Work more on $\left|S(\left|f\right|,\dot{\mathcal{P}})-S(\left|f\right|,\dot{\mathcal{Q}})\right|<\left|S(f,\dot{\mathcal{P}})-S(f,\dot{\mathcal{Q}})\right|$ but of course only ${}\le{}$ is the goal.

Comment: @GEdgar It seems you were right. Could you please check my solution in the edited question? How is the boundedness of $f$ used?

Comment: Related question (perhaps a duplicate): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316090/the-absolute-value-of-a-riemann-integrable-function-is-riemann-integrable