# Integrals of a function and its absolute value

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, improper-integrals, absolute-value, riemann-integration

Is the following proposition true?

Let $f(x)$ be a real-valued function defined on $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$, and suppose that the integral, 
$$
I = \int_a^b f(x) dx,
$$
exists in the sense of Riemann integral. If  $0< |I| < \infty$, then
$$
0< \frac{1}{|I|}\int_a^b |f(x)| dx<\infty.
$$

Comment: Dividing by $\lvert I\rvert$ does not change anything to the two bounds (upper and lower), so might as well phrase the question without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The absolute value of a Riemann integrable function is Riemann integrable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316090/the-absolute-value-of-a-riemann-integrable-function-is-riemann-integrable), so $\int_a^b |f(x)| \ dx < \infty$. In addition, you must have $0<\int_a^b |f(x)| \ dx$, for if the integral is zero then $|f(x)|=0$ almost everywhere on $[a,b]$, which would imply $\int_a^b f(x) \ dx = 0$ (i.e., $|I|=0$). Since $0<|I|<\infty$ as well, you do indeed get the result that $0<\frac{1}{|I|}\int_a^b|f(x)| \ dx <\infty$.